# How to have a map of function's pointers?

Tags: go

I need to write a parser and I have different function for each case. I'd like to assign a function for each key. Like that:

```
var myMap = map[string]funcPtr {
    "1C": func1C,
    "1D": func1D,
}
```

I'd like to use like this:

```
func func1C(){
  fmt.Print...
}
func func1D(){
  fmt.Print...
}

test := "1D"
f, err := myMap[test]
f()  // or myMap[test]()   that'll call func1D()
```

Basically, a different function per key.

What's the best solution for that?

Comment: The type would be `map[string]func()` (as the map maps string to functions without arguments and no return value).

Comment: What have you tried, what problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it as (in the most basic instance) as `map[keyType]func` (that's a map from whatever hashable `keyType` you happen to have, to a function taking no arguments and having no return value).

If you have a more involved function signature, you can declare a type for it, then use that type to define your map:

```
type myFunc func(int, int) int
var dispatch[string]myFunc

func init() {
        dispatch["add"] = func(a, b int) int { return a + b }
}
```

Another example that may be illustative follows ([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/80piyTKWGQj)):

```
type printFunc func(string)

func sayHello(name string) {
    fmt.Println("Hello", name)
}

func sayGoodbye(name string) {
    fmt.Println("Goodbye", name)
}

func main() {
    dispatch := map[string]printFunc{
        "Alice": sayHello,
        "Bob":   sayGoodbye,
    }

    for _, name := range []string{"Alice", "Bob"} {
        if f, ok := dispatch[name]; ok {
            f(name)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("No entry for", name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect and what I wanted. Thanks!